# Android Studio 3 - It is possible to take a screenshot or record screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.0

In latest version of Android Studio android monitor was changed to android profiler. Android profiler it's great but I don't see any option to take a screenshots or record device screen. So my question is where are now capturing options?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can still access them through the LogCat tab.

[image]

Comment: Why so hidden tho?!  Why should I even have to search Google to find this?  It was very clear before...   Also, there seems to be a new bug when I press the Recapture button, it changes the window size.

Comment: Not worked for me... giving "Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device: EOF" error...

Comment: @VikaS you could have just googled https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941745/unexpected-error-while-obtaining-screenshot-from-device-eof

Answer (score 11):

It's still in LogCat but below. You can click a ">>" button to reveal a list of hidden buttons.

[image]

Comment: good information for new users where logcat tab is not maximized

Answer (score 0):

If Android Studio's recording video feature is not available and you are a MacOS user you can use `QuickTime Player`

```
File -> New Screen Recording
```

To  make screenshots

```
Command + Shift + 4
```