# Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device: EOF

Tags: android, screenshot

When I try to make a screenshot in Android Studio from some of my projects (by pressing the camera icon), I get the following message:

```
"Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device: EOF"
```

I can make a screenshot of the same image if I click the camera icon after opening a totally different project.  Is there some corrupted file associated with the project that needs to be deleted and replaced?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into this problem recently - everything had been working fine previously.
Apparently it started when I migrated to SDK 26 a few weeks ago. This fixed it for me:
- shut down Studio
- rename adb.exe in Android\sdk\platform-tools to .saf
- copy the older adb.exe from Android\android-sdk\platform-tools to Android\sdk\platform-tools
- restart Studio

So basically replace the SDK 26 adb.exe with an older version...

Comment: THANK YOU!  I replaced the adb.exe file in Android\sdk\platform-tools with an adb.exe file from another folder and the screen shot procedure now works beautifully.  I previously filed a bug report with the Google Android Studio Team.  I will pass your solution on to them.

Comment: Thank you very much!
For those who don't know where to get the oder adb.exe from: 
Download platform-tools r28.0.0 from 
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.0-windows.zip
and use the adb.exe from the downloaded zip

Comment: After adding old version of platform-tools, Android Stuido tries to update it. Beware and cancel it.

Comment: Where do I get an older adb.exe from ?

Comment: new version adb is evil

Comment: What about on linux?

Answer (score 1):

In my case restarting the Android Studio worked for me.
Go to *File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart*.

But for someone who still has a problem after restarting. If you have `getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);` set (normally used to avoid screenshots), it will also prevent you from taking screenshots from Android Studio, generating the same error Unexpected Error while obtaining screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I try this way it working :

1. Create adb_capture.txt with content

   ```
   REM ====================

   REM set varible _MyTime for filename
   FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%a IN ("%time%") DO (
   SET _MyTime=%%a%%b%%c%%d
   )
   REM adb root
   REM adb remount
   adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/Download/s1.png
   adb pull /sdcard/Download/s1.png
   adb shell rm /sdcard/Download/s1.png
   REM every file have different name by time
   rename s1.png %_MyTime%.png

   REM===============
   ```
2. Change file name to adb_capture.bat than click run which will capture phone screen